# Tidy up walls when moving out of a rented room

Tags: repair, painting

I am moving out of a rented room in a week, and they are going to charge me £150 to repaint the white walls.

More importantly, I look a hook off the wall (one of the command stick-on ones) and it made a hole in the wall:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this myself? I have no idea how much they would charge me. Would normal filler work?

Also if I took a sample of the paint into a DIY store do you think I could touch up the walls myself with a paint brush? I did spill red wine down one, so that is quite a big area...

Comment: Local laws vary, of course, but in most places in the US, needing a touch-up coat of paint is considered normal wear-and-tear on the rental property and not something the tenant is responsible for. This typically includes small holes from hanging pictures and such, although your tear may be beyond that scope. Things may be different in the UK, of course, but definitely something to look in to.

Comment: When removing the 3M hooks, you need to follow the correct procedure to the letter.  I prefer the pull-tab ones where the adhesive stretches like Gumby.  If you've stayed there for years, they should be repainting as part of normal wear and tear.

Comment: Thanks, the walls have a few scuffs on, but the paint seems unusually prone to damage (touching the wall with anything seems to cause a dark 'scratch' - something I have never experienced before - and the tea I once splashed on it would not wash off without damaging the paint). It is very clear in my agreement that they will charge me to repaint it - but I haven't heard a final decision. I have decided to leave it and see what they say. I have rented for ~5 years and have never marked the walls before (not even including this hole they now look terrible with colored marks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seal the raw drywall facing paper with wall primer, then skim it with joint compound or spackle using a taping knife. Let it dry and lightly sand it gently with a block.

To fix the paint you'll probably need to paint entire walls. It's unlikely that you'll get a match of color and sheen that won't be noticeable, even if you feather and blend it well. You can probably find a suitable match using the hundreds of paint chips available at most paint stores. Bring a few home and compare in the room's natural light. Slight changes in color are often undetectable at corners, where the light dramatically changes the hue anyway.